# Finding the third side of a triangle given the area

Tags: triangles

I know the area and the lengths of two sides (a and b) of a non-right triangle. I also know P1 (vertex between a and c) and P2 (vertex between a and b).

I already know this much:

Perimeter = $ \frac{(a+b+c)}{2} $

Area = $ A=\sqrt{p(p-a)(p-b)(p-c)} $

How do I simplify the above two equations to solve for c? (Obviously, this is just algebra, but it's long enough that it is prone to error; I've tried this by hand now and gotten a different set of solutions each time.)

Comment: The angle $\theta$ between $a$ and $b$ is not fixed, hence neither it is the area $$\Delta = \frac{1}{2}ab\sin(\theta).$$

Comment: Given two sides and area, most of the time when there is a triangle with these properties, there are exactly two.

Comment: It is not very clear what is given and what is not. We have to find $c$ given $a,b,p$, or $a,b,\Delta$, or something else?

Answer (score 1):

By cosine rule,
\begin{align}
c^2&=a^2+b^2-2ab\cos\gamma
\tag{1}\label{1}
, 
\end{align}
And from the formula for the area
\begin{align}
2S&=ab\sin\gamma
,\\
\sin\gamma&=\frac {2S}{ab}
,
\end{align}

so, with
\begin{align}
\cos\gamma&=\pm\sqrt{1-\sin^2\gamma}
=
\pm\sqrt{1-\frac {4S^2}{a^2b^2}}
=\pm\frac{\sqrt{a^2b^2-4S^2}}{ab}
\end{align}

\eqref{1} becomes

\begin{align}
c^2&=a^2+b^2\pm2\sqrt{a^2b^2-4S^2}
.
\end{align}

Answer (score 0):

$s\;$ is the conventional way of representing the semiperimeter $\frac{a+b+c}2$ of the triangle with sides $a\,,b\,,c$.

$\sqrt{s(s-a)(s-b)(s-c)}=
\frac{\sqrt{-a^4-b^4-c^4+2b^2c^2+2c^2a^2+2a^2b^2}}4=\Delta$

Solving for $c$,
$$c=\sqrt{a^2+b^2\pm 2\sqrt{a^2b^2-4\Delta^2}}$$

where area $=\Delta$

Answer (score 0):

Suppose we know $$K = |\triangle ABC|, \quad a, b,$$  and we wish to determine $c$.  Then 
$$\begin{align*} 16K^2 &= (a+b+c)(-a+b+c)(a-b+c)(a+b-c) \\
&= \left((a+b)^2 - c^2 \right)\left(c^2 - (a-b)^2 \right) \\
&= -c^4 + \left( (a-b)^2 + (a+b)^2 \right) c^2 - (a+b)^2 (a-b)^2 \\
&= -c^4 + 2(a^2 + b^2) c^2 - (a^2 - b^2)^2. \end{align*}$$
This of course is a quadratic in $c^2$.  We can complete the square to get
$$\begin{align*} 0 &= (c^2 - (a^2+b^2))^2 + (a^2-b^2)^2 - (a^2+b^2)^2 + 16K^2 \\
&= (c^2 - (a^2+b^2))^2 - 4a^2 b^2 + 16K^2, \end{align*}$$
from which we obtain $$c^2 = a^2 + b^2 \pm 2\sqrt{a^2 b^2 - 4K^2}.$$  Note that we must always have $ab \ge 2K$, as the area of the triangle is maximized when the angle between sides of fixed length $a$ and $b$ is right; thus the square root is always well-defined.  Furthermore, the AM-GM inequality guarantees that when $a, b > 0$, $a^2 + b^2 \ge 2 \sqrt{a^2 b^2}$, hence $c^2$ admits exactly two positive solutions whenever the strict inequality $ab > 2K$ is satisfied, and one unique solution when $ab = 2K$ and the triangle is right.